# Web Messaging - sending messages

Tags: html, web, messaging

I have question :) Can I send message via Web Messaging or not to other tab in browser? For example I have openede my site, and now watching on other site. And when some condition will be pass my site sends messages which makes alert on the other page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have control over both pages, the answer is "yes", provided you open the second window from the first. `window.postMessage` only works if you can get a handle to the `window`. Therefore, if your background site were to invoke `window.open()` to get to your "other" site, then you could retain a handle to it in your first page's script.

As far as opening it in a tab goes, you'll have to [specify that in your browser options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript).

Comment: Uh. What, if I have control on first page and second page is, for example facebook?

Comment: Then you can either petition Facebook to set up an alert API, or write a greasemonkey script or similar to install a message event listener. But it's not something you'll be able to rely on being available for anybody else.